# The el-dialog layer in Internet Explorer appears incorrectly(IE version includes 1809, 21H1 etc.)

Tags: internet-explorer, element

[The el-dialog layer in Internet Explorer appears incorrectly(IE version includes 1809, 21H1 etc.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfLSM.png)

Comment: Maybe you should include some problematic code/layout?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute to el-Dialog modal-Append-to-body ="false"